# Another ubuntu one music problem with ID3-Tags ("unknown artist" problem)

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3, id3

I started using ubuntu one a few days ago. I put some MP3s into the cloud music folder and I can play them just fine in the music web and andriod applications.

The problem is that all files are sorted under "unknown artist" and "unknown album" and the title is either the file name or a part of it (which is from the service "guessing the title" I guess).

It seems the problem happened before. I looked in the FAQ, which said this happens with m4a files, but I use mp3 files. The ID3 tags are correct and are tagged with ID3v1 and ID3v2. I read to wait, until the service can catch up with the tagging, so I waited 24 hours, still nothing. Every single file is still listed under unknown artist/unknown album.

I'm running out of options here :/

Answer (score 1):

Diverse MP3 players (and probably the UBUNTU One cloud, too) don't support ID3v2.4. Your tagging software has to write the tags in ID3v2.3 (and ISO 8859-1).

Answer (score 0):

You should open a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ about your problem.